# Getting error creating date format for folder

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code that creates a date format that will allow me to create a folder for the previous day. The problem is that if the day is between 1 and 9 it create an error were the date stamp comes up with -1-04-2019 instead of 08-04-2019. The echo statement for  %day%-%month%-%year% is correct 09-04-2019.

```
SET day=%date:~0,2%
SET Month=%date:~3,2%
SET Year=%date:~6,4%
SET /A Yesterday=%day-1
echo %Yesterday%-%Month%-%Year%
echo %day%-%Month%-%Year%
```

Result =

```
-1-04-2019
09-04-2019
```

Is there a way to add the zero so i can get the day between 1 to 9 with a leading zero.

I have tried an If statement :-

```
IF "%date:~0,1%" == "0" SET day=0%date:~1,1%
```

or

```
IF "%date:~0,1%" == " " SET day=0%date:~1,1%
```

Regards
Michael

Comment: You are missing a % on the line: SET /A Yesterday=%day-1 should become SET /A Yesterday=%day%-1

Comment: There are so many questions and answers on StackOverFlow that answer your question.  Please consider using the search function in the future before you ask another question. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I totally agree with Squashman! Anyway, just to point it out: leading zeros lets `set /A` treat numbers as octal ones, so calculations using `08` and `09` cannot work as these are invalid octal numbers. And there is no date/time data format in batch scripting, so computations with such values is always a mess; switch to or borrow from a language that can properly handle such data (I guess there is no almost language besides batch that can't)...

Answer (score 1):

If you leverage [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you can easily get your required string without having to perform calculations in the event of yesterday being the previous month, or year; (or possibly accounting for leap years etc.)

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('dd-MM-yyy')"') Do @MD "%%A"
```

Or even simpler:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "MD (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('dd-MM-yyy')">Nul
```

Comment: I'd set a variable so he/the batch later knows what day yesterday was. ;-)

Comment: @LotPings, it all depends upon what the intention is, based on the question and title, the intent was to create a directory named using the required date pattern string. This does exactly that, anything else is outside of the scope of the question.